# How to make a Google Script fill in the closest row of cells to the top with a value and then stop without repeating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a function (using Google Scripts) that fills in the row of blank cells closest to the top in Google Spreadsheets with a certain value. The problem is that I don't want it repeating itself when it is done or overwriting existing data. I figured I could use some while and for loops to make this work, but so far I have had little success. Here is my existing code:

```
function add() {
 var done = false
 while(done === false) {
  for(var i = 2; i <= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getMaxRows(); i++) 
   while((SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(i, 1).isBlank()) === true && (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(i - 1, 1).isBlank()) === true) {
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(i, 1).setValue("'... Complicated'")
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(i, 2).setValue(Session.getActiveUser())
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(i, 3).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
     done = true;
  }

 }
}
```

I was thinking that after the text had been filled in to the closest blank cell to the top, the `while` loop outside the `for` loop should make the formula stop, because of the `done = true` script that I put at the bottom of the second `while` loop, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: There is only one row of blank cells?

Comment: What do you mean, @SandyGood

Comment: How many rows of blank cells are there?  One? Multiple?  Always a different number?  That will affect how the code is written.

Comment: Each row has four cells, so all of them have to be blank. @SandyGood

Answer (score 0):

Your `FOR` loop has no function body brackets.

```
for(var i = 2; i <= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3").getMaxRows(); i++)
```

Missing `{`

I rewrote your code.  It uses the number of columns.  In this code, the number of columns is set manually.

```
function add() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

 var numbrOfRows = theSheet.getMaxRows();
 var numberOfColumns = 5;

 var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  for(var i = 2; i <= numbrOfRows; i++) { //This goes through all the rows

    var objCountToColumnLetter = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C", 4:"D", 5:"E"};

    //This goes through each cell in the row (Columns)
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
      var isthisCellBlank = theSheet.getRange(i, 1).isBlank();

      if (isthisCellBlank) {
        var rngOne = objCountToColumnLetter[j] + i.toString();
        var rngTwo = objCountToColumnLetter[j] + i.toString();
        var rngThree = objCountToColumnLetter[j] + i.toString();

        theSheet.getRange(rngOne).setValue("'... Complicated'");
        theSheet.getRange(rngTwo).setValue(Session.getActiveUser());
        theSheet.getRange(rngThree).setValue(userEmail);
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: A popup comes up and says `The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.` Also, I noticed an error in your script above. inside your if formula, you are writing the three values all into the same box.

Comment: I'm providing a suggestion about the general logic of how the process might work.  You're right, I configured the notation for the `getRange()` method incorrectly.  I changed the code to a different example.  If you are checking each column in the same row for an empty cell, then you can match the iteration number to a column letter in order to set the range.  That's what the object is for.